# Posting on facebook page as page not user

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk

I'm trying to post to the facebook page as admin. the post are always appearing as user not as if the post is held by page.

here is the code, I took a sample of posting on user wall and added manages_page permission and change me/feed to page_id

**Java File :**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Session session, final SessionState state,
            final Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

private Button shareButton;

private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");


private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";

private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
TextView text;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
    text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view
            .findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setPublishPermissions("manage_pages");
    shareButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
    shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            publishStory();
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        pendingPublishReauthorization = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(
                PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, false);
    }
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }

    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, pendingPublishReauthorization);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
        Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        shareButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (pendingPublishReauthorization
                && state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
            publishStory();
        }
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        shareButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

private void publishStory() {
    final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {

        // Check for publish permissions
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();

        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                    this, PERMISSIONS);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);


        //  session.open(session.getAccessToken(), callback);
            return;
        }

        final Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("message", "Testing app");


        final Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject()
                        .getInnerJSONObject();
                String postId = null;
                try {
                    postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
                }
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if (error != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            postId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };

        Request request = new Request(session, "667572223265719/feed", postParams,
                HttpMethod.POST, callback);

        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();
    }
}

private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset,
        Collection<String> superset) {
    for (String string : subset) {
        if (!superset.contains(string)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Hi i've used your code , but after login , I'm getting error 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.
on  session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you're not fetching the Page Access Token, and use the User Access Token instead. Requesting the `manage_pages` permission is the right thing to do, but afterwards you need to make a call to

```
/me/accounts
```

to get the individual Page's Access Token. Afterwards, you have to use this Access Token to make your request to

```
{page_id}/feed
```

Comment: can you provide a sample code, cuz i didnt catch it how to do it

Comment: Hi i've used your code , but after login , I'm getting error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request. on session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);